# send http post with header in android(This code works perfectly-I forgot to put the internet permission in manifest file that's why it didn't worked)

Tags: android, http, post, http-headers

I know there are a few posts on this topic, but I just can figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I have to send by post some parameter to a `php server` that requires a login.

Here is the code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String postUrl = "http://dev.demo.fr/Contacts/areaGet.php";

HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("dev.demo.fr", 80, "http");

httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("*****", "*****"));
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("language_id", "1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country_id", "1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postal_code", "42830"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}

System.out.println(response);
```

**IMPORTANT**: The username and password are `uncoded` in here:

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("*****", "*****"));
```

The problem is that when I do this: `System.out.println(response);` `it prints out null` and I just don't know why!!!!

Thank you for your answers!!!

Comment: If you are running these code on Android 3.0 system or later, make sure these code are executed from background thread, not the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get response "null" from server it means your request is not successfully posted on server.